# Packet filter (firewall) for a /29 network

Tags: networking, ip, routing, firewall, subnet

My ISP routes a /29 network (8 IP addresses). The first and the last is of course network and broadcast address and the second is assigned to the modem by the ISP. The modem has an ethernet LAN port with the /29 network that I can use. Unfortunately I am not able to access or replace the modem, only ISP has access to it. It needs to be treated as black box for this discussion. My endpoint is the LAN connection of the modem which provides the /29 network.

Of course, I can assign the remaining 5 IP addresses to different machines and connect them to the modem via the Ethernet port. This is what I am doing right now.

However, I would like to have a packet filter (Firewall) in between. Usually a firewall needs two interfaces with two subnets. I could technically split the /29 into two /30 networks and put the firewall in between them.

Another option would be to assign all five static IPs to the firewall and do NAT and port forwarding.

A third option would be to make all L2 traffic pass my firewall, configure it as a bridge and use basic L2 filtering.

None of these options sound appealing to me.

Is there a good way to put a firewall in front of my IP network *without* requiring NAT or L2 filtering?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient detail. What make and model modem, and what kind of connection do you have.  Generally a /29 is routed over another subnet - so if its an available option - and if you have a /29 it typically is - ditch the ISP router or convert it into a minimal device which converts all traffic over it to ethernet (or if its PPPo? terminate that on your real router).  Its impossible to prov8de you more detail wothout knowing more detail.

Comment: I wrote that I don't have access to the modem. Per contract, only ISP has access and my endpoint is the LAN port of the modem with the /29 network and one of the IPs is assigned to the modem itself. I'll clarify this in the post.

Comment: Yes, but you did not advise the kind if connection or device. If you cant change anything related to the endpoint, and cant replace it then you are stuck with the options you listed - unless you come up with some kind of frankenhack deploying proxyarp which is not that for off a layer 2 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the entire /29 would be on the "inside" interface of the firewall, the firewall itself would be connected using a completely separate /31 (or /30), and the ISP would *route* the main /29 via your firewall... It's worth trying to call your ISP and ask if they can do that kind of "point to point" configuration.

If that's not possible, fake it by using **proxy ARP** on the firewall. As long as it answers ARP queries to the router, it'll receive traffic for those IP addresses, even if they are not actually configured on the firewall.

This works with a Linux-based firewall (and the general idea should work with e.g. OpenBSD) but no guarantees about appliances:

1. Configure the firewall's "inside" interface with an address from the /29 as usual.

   ```
   ip addr add 193.256.181.193/26 dev int0
   ```
2. Configure the firewall's "outside" interface with the *same* address, but make it a /32.

   On Linux, you can use "point-to-point" addressing style, specifying the modem's address as the "peer".

   ```
   ip addr add 193.256.181.193 peer 193.256.181.254/32 dev ext0
   ```

   If that's not possible, use a regular /32 and separately add a "local" route for the modem's address.

   ```
   ip addr add 193.256.181.193/32 dev ext0
   ip route add 193.256.181.254/32 dev ext0
   ```
3. Add the default route as usual.

   ```
   ip route add default via 193.256.181.254 dev ext0
   ```
4. Enable proxy-ARP on the "outside" interface. On Linux you can use either the in-kernel implementation (enabled through `sysctl`), or a userspace daemon ("parpd").

   Because the in-kernel implementation confuses me to no end, using `parpd` was simpler (and also because in my case I needed to configure *exceptions* to the whole-subnet proxying, which parpd can do but the kernel cannot), so here's an /etc/parpd.conf:

   ```
   interface ext0
       # Make the ISP router think the entire subnet is still on-link
       proxy 193.256.181.192/26
       # But don't answer for the ISP router's own address
       ignore 193.256.181.254
   ```

   You can also enable ARP proxying for the "inside" interface, so that your statically-configured LAN hosts could simply continue having the ISP router's address as their "default gateway" without the need to immediately change it everywhere:

   ```
   interface int0
       # Make the LAN hosts think the ISP router is still on-link
       proxy 193.256.181.254
   ```

   The in-kernel proxy ARP implementation on Linux can be found under `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.ext0.proxy_arp[_pvlan]` as well as `ip neigh add .. proxy`. (After several attempts I still don't exactly know whether the latter requires the sysctl to be enabled or whether they're orthogonal.)

   Note that "proxy" in this case does not mean *relaying* the requests (though that's also possible); instead the firewall *itself* will be answering on behalf of the proxied addresses.
5. That's all, now just treat the firewall as a standard router and write your iptables rules.

The advantage of this mechanism (compared to e.g. NAT or ebtables *brouting*<sup>1</sup>) is that aside from the "outside" interface looking slightly weird, your firewall continues to work as a *completely standard* layer-3 router – proxy-ARP doesn't alter the IP packets in any way, and very nearly achieves the same result as if the ISP had simply routed the /29 via your firewall.

(The same method also works with IPv6 using proxy-NDP, but hopefully you won't be needing that and can just get the ISP to route it properly, e.g. via DHCPv6-PD?)

---

Note that even in your initial plan of splitting the /29 into two /30's, proxy-ARP would remain needed because the ISP's router would be completely unaware of the split – it would keep issuing ARP queries for the entire /29.

If the answer is that you can call the ISP and ask them to adjust the routing so that two /30's can be used... well, then you can also ask them to just route the entire /29 to your firewall in the first place (in which case they would assign a dedicated point-to-point /30 for the modem–firewall link).

---

<sup>1</sup> The Linux software bridge supports a feature where certain packets can be lifted up to L3 processing (routing/iptables), while other packets continue to be forwarded by the L2 bridge. This is used by some firewall appliances such as Untangle. It is horrible and I hope I will never see it used on a network again.

Comment: Awesome, this is pretty much what I was looking for! I wanted to confirm if these are typos or not: You write /29 but sometimes you use /26 (for example `ip addr add 193.256.181.193/26 dev int0`). You use 193.256.181.193/32 but for perp.conf it's 193.256.181.192/26. (192 instead of 193). These should all be 193 (not 192) and /29 (not /26), correct?

Comment: The only thing, as you wrote is that the "outside interface looks slightly weird". I am trying to wrap my head around assigning the same IP address twice -- once with /32 and once with /29. Is this legal? How does Linux know which interface to send packets to when the destination has the IP address that matches both interfaces?

Comment: I used /26 because I'm basically copying my example from an existing Linux router, which has a nearly identical setup with a /26 network. (Even the example IP addresses actually come from the existing system.) So in general, adjust the prefix length to your needs, be it /29 or something else (except where the example has /32 that's deliberate and it should remain /32).

Comment: In `parpd.conf`, the parameter just describes a whole address range, e.g. 192.168.2.0/24 or 192.168.2.128/25, so the "zeroth" address is used. In `ip addr`, the parameter is a _specific host address_ together with the network's size/netmask, e.g. 192.168.2.5/24 (meaning 192.168.2.5 in a /24 network). So in my example, the firewall is in fact 193.256.181.193 but it's in the 193.256.181.192/26 network (I used the 1st address for my firewall, while the ISP uses the last one). _[The addresses are very slightly anonymized, hence "256".]_

Comment: Depends on what kind of destination you're thinking about – do you mean the hosts in your /29? Those destinations actually _don't_ match both interfaces. They will only match int0 (which has the whole /29), but not ext0 (because it's configured for a /32 only) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually a firewall needs two interfaces with two subnets.

The firewall would also do NAT as required, which means only the "external" subnet is your /29, and the "internal" subnet is a private address range, which can be as big as you like (e.g. `10.0.0.0/8`).

And this can be "static" NAT, so you can have 5 internal IPs and map them one-to-one on your 5 external IPs. Or anything else you fancy.

So there's really no drawback on using NAT in your situation. NAT is not restricted to the "map the whole internal subnet to a single IP address" which is done by default on home routers.

> Is there a good way to put a firewall in front of my IP network without requiring NAT or L2 filtering?

I mean, you either stay on L2, then you need L2 filtering, or you go to L3, then you need routing, and therefore NAT. So it's going to be one or the other.

Wasting external IP addresses for internal firewalled machines is not a good use of expensive resources like IP addresses, just because you "don't like NAT" (or whatever your reason is).